# civivolunteer extension

Tags: extension, civivolunteer

my civi version is 4.5.2
I wanted to activate civiVolunteer at administer. but there is no civivolunteer.
the civicontribution etc. is there.
how can I activate the civivolunteer?

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the extension? It is not automatically shipped with CiviCRM. Check here to see how you can install extensions: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Extensions

Comment: thx. I dont have the extension civivolunteer. and this link is a little to complicate for me.

Comment: I would recommend you find a local expert who can help you? In any case, you need to install the CiviVolunteer extension, it is not part of the core CiviCRM download. And if you want to make good use of what CiviCRM can offer, knowing what extensions are and how to install  them is helpful!